# Android : How to launch specific Activity of other apps from our app?

Tags: android

If I want to launch other applications from my application then I can write the following code.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

But in my scenario, I don't want to open the launcher `Activity` of other application and I want to open other specific `Activity`.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open other specific Activity

To launch other Activity from package instead of launcher use `PackageInfo.activities` to gell all activities declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("com.package.address", 0);
ActivityInfo[] activitiesInfos = packageInfo.activities;
ActivityInfo activityToLaunch=activitiesInfos[0]; //<< activity which want to start

// Create ComponentName object using packageName and activity name
ComponentName compName=new ComponentName(
                                     activityToLaunch.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activityToLaunch.name);
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(compName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I am getting PackageManagerNameNotFoundException. Whether I have to mention anything in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Sridhar: ok use `List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList =          context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);` to get all instead package names then check you are getting package name or not

Comment: @Sridhar: Answer help u or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String _PACKAGE_NAME = "app package name which you want to open";
private static final String _CLASS_NAME = _PACKAGE_NAME + ".activity class which you want to access";
```

and then call this

```
    try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName(_PACKAGE_NAME, _CLASS_NAME);
                // Set your data in my case i have url 
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(playlistUrl));
                // If "package" extra is set, app will be able to show your app name as a title
                intent.putExtra("package", getPackageName());
               startActivity(intent);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // app is not installed, let's ask the user to install it.
               AppNotFoundDialog();
            }
```